# VictoryJS Switch Statement in style.data.stroke

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set different colors for different slices of `<VictoryPie />` depending on `data.x` but I'm having trouble figuring out how... Here's the code:

```
  style={{
    data: {
      stroke: (data) => {
        switch (data.x) {
          case 'one':
          case 'two':
          case 'three': return colors.aa;
          case 'four':
          case 'five':
          case 'six':
          case 'seven':
          case 'eight':
          case 'nine': return colors.bb;
          default: return strokeColor;
        }
      },
    },
  }}
```

`colors.aa`, `colors.bb`, `strokeColor` are all string variables for different '#hex'.

There's no console error or any syntax error with eslint which is making this hard to know what's wrong... Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're basing on "labels" (or values that are strings, use `.xName`):

```
  style={{
    data: {
      stroke: (data) => {
        switch (data.xName) {
          case 'one':
          case 'two':
          case 'three': return colors.aa;
          case 'four':
          case 'five':
          case 'six':
          case 'seven':
          case 'eight':
          case 'nine': return colors.bb;
          default: return strokeColor;
        }
      },
    },
  }}
```